# Android Toast Message is not showing

Tags: android

I have Button.When the user click the button, there are some condition, that condition is not satisfy then need to display Toast but not showing Toast Message...

Code: **Edited**

```
 Button addMe = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addMe);
    addMe.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(selectedReason.equals("--Select--")){
                   Log.i("TAG","-----");
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Reason can not be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }else if(selectedType.equals("--Select--")){
                   Toast.makeText(getParent(), "Discount type can not be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }else{
                   if(selectedType.equals("Value")){
                       if(spc_amount.getText().toString().equals("")){
                           Log.i("TAG","-----");
                           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Discount type can not be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }else{
                           if(Double.parseDouble(spc_amount.getText().toString()) > invoiceValue){
                               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Amonut can not be grater than invoice", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }else{
                               Discount dis = new Discount();
                               dis.setCriteriaName(selectedReason);
                               dis.setDiscountValue(Double.parseDouble(spc_amount.getText().toString()));
                               spDisList.put(1,dis);
                               tl.removeAllViews();
                            loadTableLayout();
                           }

                       }
                   }
               }
           }
    });
```

I have tried context with `getParent()` , `getApplicationContext()` , `SpecialDiscountActivity.this`  & `getBaseContext()` but not working....

This `Toast` message coming under the `Tab Activity Group`

Comment: As pointed by one comment below, you also should enable 'Show notification' for the application in order Toast to work for you.

Comment: Why did you edit the code to include the solution? It should be preserved to contain the error, otherwise this question does not make sense.

Comment: Also a common gotcha: if you are not in the main thread you need to call `runOnUiThread`. E.g.
 `runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did like this

```
Toast.makeText(SalesActivityGroup.group.getParent(), "Amount can not be 
                                grater than invoice", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 129):

Try:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Reason can not be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

It's the .show() that you've omitted everywhere that causes all your toasts to instatiate, but never execute.

Comment: Oh god why. Been a couple hours stuck because of that!

Comment: This. Is. Silly.

Comment: I have a feeling I am going to make this error quite a few times. If you do jQuery it's kinda similar to their method to `.show()` and `.hide()` DOM elements, so if you remember that the Toast is always hidden by default that might help remember to do the `.show()`

Comment: I have a .show() and I am calling right from the activity's onCreate method and I also have use `this`, `MainActivity.this`, `getApplication()`, `getApplicationContext()`, `getBaseContext()` all to no avail. The toast showed on the first two test and never showed again. No code changes between that period.

Comment: @RichardMcFriendOluwamuyiwa Yet there's always that little detail you missed, I know from first hand experience..

Answer (score 77):

Please excuse me if this isn't the solution to your problem, but I accidentally unchecked the 'Show notification' setting of the application once. It may be an idea go into your device settings/application/manager and check this setting.

Comment: I would have never thought of that... Thought this setting only hides the notification icon of my service, but you're right, it did hide toasts as well

Comment: Whoa, I was extremely skeptical of this, but at least on 4.4.4, disabling notifications also stops toasts from displaying.

Comment: I did this too and wasted 30 minutes of my time :(

Answer (score 64):

I think you are missing `.show();`
It should be...

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Amount can not be grater than invoice",
                                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thanks @LalitPoptani  I did using Toast.makeText(SalesActivityGroup.group.getParent(), "Amonut can not be grater than invoice", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: @NagkeeranPiraba one more thing about your question is that you should have mentioned that you are using Tab.

Comment: I cant believe this was my mistake too! haha. Thanks a lot for the heads up!

Answer (score 56):

Just restart your device! It solved my problem.

Comment: OMG yes, for anyone reading this answer, he means "restart your device". I almost downvoted your answer...  xP

Comment: Dude, you just saved me a whole day! I was showing a toast like `Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` and it wasn't appearing suddenly. Got me questioning my abilities and meaning of life... Device restart fixed it!

Comment: Wow.  Works in 2020.  Pixel 2 Device Build QQ1A.191205.008).  Excellent!

Comment: This worked for me on my emulated AVD Pixel 3a. I had tried everything else. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on MiA2. Good job I found this. I was just about to start modifying code that had been working!

Comment: It works, thanks. Anyone knows why and how?

Comment: If someone told me I would not believe, but it actually was the case for me on the Google Nexus 5x (Android 8.1).

Comment: Dude, you are very nice person! I spent about an hour to solve that, It was actually that simple! I've almost started to read Android sources to understand the root of this problem:)

Answer (score 15):

Maybe you are not in the UI thread? Try this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Comment: Not calling on UI thread trips me up more often than I'm willing to admit.

Answer (score 11):

If Toast is not showing that means either you have not called `show()` method or you are not on **UI thread**

Ideally, you should create a helper method to show Toast like this on UI thread

```
 /** Execute Toast on UI thread **/
 private fun showToast(message: String) {

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            // Code here will run in UI thread
            Toast.makeText(
                this, 
                message,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Calling the empty Handler constructor off the main thread will create a Handler that doesn't post to the main thread. You need to specify the main Looper.

Answer (score 9):

Just bumped across this issue and was wondering how a simple Toast is not appearing. After few trials it struck me to check the notification setting of the app and Voila.

I switched the notification setting ON and it started showing up. I searched and came across the below link, which talks about the same:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35013

Comment: It happend with me as well on Android 9, this one solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There could be two possibilities:

1 - You have not append `.show();` at the very end of `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)`.

2 - There could be situation you are not passing **right context**

For that try passing `getActivity().getApplicationContext();`

which in my case resolved the issue.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 6):

Simply restart your emulator not fixed my problem.

1. Close emulator
2. Tools -> Avd Manager
3. In the device list click on "drop-down icon" under "Action" column.
4. Cold boot now

Now reinstalling the app it will work.

Answer (score 5):

Some times Emulator is hanging so restarting the emulator fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the context of the Activity

like,

```
Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this,"Reason can not be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

**if this is not working, please put a `log.i();` in your each condition may be its going to the last else and you are not getting the Toast.**

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I wasn't running from Main thread, this fixed it:

```
    val mainActivity = (tabHostActivity.activityContext() as MainActivity)
    mainActivity.lifecycleScope.launch{ //Dispatchers.Main, follows lifecycle 
        Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "my awesome message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Cold boot your device!
It can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there may be an error or nullPointerException in the message that we want to print with Toast message. If this error occured then app will simply ignore the Toast message. I had the same issue. I printed the message in Log and found the error, after that I changed the message in Toast. And it worked as I wanted. Try it!!

Answer (score 0):

Android throttles toats so if you send to many they just stop showing up, instead you can use Snackbar:

```
Snackbar.make(myView, "This is a snack.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying on UIThread or MainThread

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "show on uithread", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Reason can not be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score -2):

Complimer checks all the code and if there is a critical error, it ignores even the lines before the error section and therfore you will not see the "Toast".
Simply, comment the lines which error happens in them (you can find the error lines in Logcat)
Now you can see the "Toast" and can analyze your problem.