# Toast message doesn't show up on actual phone while it shows in emulator

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toast

I'm trying to create an android application. One part is to make sure that toast message shows. It works when I'm running the app on the android studio emulator, but it doesn't show when I'm running on actual Samsung phone

It's about a thousand line code, so I don't think it's helpful to copy all of it. So, I'd like to know if there is any common issues that can make toast messages to show in emulator but not in actual phone.

-- EDIT --

This is one of the parts where I want to toast message

```
private fun addListenerOnImageButtonHelper(intent: Intent, sensorId: Int, sensorType: Int, sensorTypeToString: String) {
    findViewById<ImageButton>(sensorId).setOnClickListener {
        if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(sensorType) != null) {
            intent.putExtra("sensor", sensorType)
            startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                "$sensorTypeToString sensor is not available on this device",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

-- EDIT --

Phone's setting to show notification was turned off. Problem Solved... Thanks

Comment: Please paste the code here which you are writing to display the toast.

Comment: paste only one example where it's happening. we don't need 1000 lines of code

Comment: Brother write your code like this any where you want to display Toast

Comment: Toast.makeText(ctx,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

Comment: in ctx pass this@YourActivity.class

Comment: @nimi0112 I just added

Comment: @shb I just added

Comment: @RahulKushwaha I think I'm using Toast right way

Comment: Did you try putting a break point on else? Check whether else block is executing or not.  Or put a Log message

Comment: @shb I just added println() statement, and it works. Else block is executing.

Comment: Try to use with `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this` !

Comment: @DineshShingadiya it seems like 'applicationContext' is the one for Kotlin grammar. Unfortunately, it doesn't work...

Comment: Then try to create your button object from `onCreate()` instead of `addListenerOnImageButtonHelper()`

Comment: @DineshShingadiya imagebutton object is created on xml file. I'm just finding those objects from addListenerOnImageButtonHelper() function

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27755101/6207294
May be notification permission for your app in physical device is off

Comment: @shb LOL... how come I turned off this setting... Thanks a lot Thank you so much I've been trying to solve this for more than a day...

Answer (score 0):

You need add `ActivityName.this` when you create `toast`

Because you want to show `toast` from `ImageButton` click

```
private fun addListenerOnImageButtonHelper(intent: Intent, sensorId: Int, sensorType: Int, sensorTypeToString: String) {
    findViewById<ImageButton>(sensorId).setOnClickListener {
        if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(sensorType) != null) {
            intent.putExtra("sensor", sensorType)
            startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this,
                "$sensorTypeToString sensor is not available on this device",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Else you need to pass `Context` as parameter in your function

Like

```
private fun addListenerOnImageButtonHelper(context: Context,intent: Intent, sensorId: Int, sensorType: Int, sensorTypeToString: String) {
    findViewById<ImageButton>(sensorId).setOnClickListener {
        if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(sensorType) != null) {
            intent.putExtra("sensor", sensorType)
            startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                "$sensorTypeToString sensor is not available on this device",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It cause an error (red line) when I changed this to MainPageActivity.this (activity name is MainPageActivity)

Comment: @Vishal Sojitra  No!

Comment: `ActivityName.this` is not required!

Comment: You can use `context` as well

Comment: I just tried applicationContext but it doesn't work