# Toast Message is not showing in emulator pixel 3a

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, toast

Another solution for: [Android Toast Message is not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803256/android-toast-message-is-not-showing)

As an absolute beginner in Android Studio I have not enough reputation to comment in the above thread, but for me this thread helped: [The system ui isn't responding in android emulator (Flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371056/the-system-ui-isnt-responding-in-android-emulator-flutter/64907873#64907873?newreg=17dc5bc0305d463394239e31823e3de2)

I found that thread on google, because always when I clicked a button, I got this message in the pixel 3a emulator after several seconds: "The system ui isn't responding". Instead of showing a Toast message.
So I searched for this message and found that thread.
After changing the "Emulated Performance - Graphics" from "Automatic" to "Hardware - GLES 2.0", the Toast message is showing.
So I could solve two problems: Not showing Toast messages and and the problem with "The system ui isn't responding"

My Toast code: `Toast.makeText(this, "This is a Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you have tried the "Cold booting".

1. Open AVD Manager
2. Under the Actions section
3. Click the dropdown button ▼
4. Then click on "Cold Boot Now".

Hope it works

Comment: Thanks, yes that worked too! But I think I have another Android Studio version. I had to click on the button "Show Advanced Settings" first. Then I am able to choose the Boot option "Cold boot". -> I think it has the same result like my method in my post.